# Supporting Multiple popups In The Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to support multiple popups within the same page. I've looked through all the answers here but none of them are exactly what I'm looking for.

My HTML/JavaScript looks like this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click,.fade').click(function() {
      $('.pop').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.click { cursor:help }

    .pop {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    display:none;
    }
    .fade {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }

    .popup {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    position:fixed;
    background:#fff; /* background of popup box */
    padding:10px; /* padding of popup box */
    z-index:10000;
    max-width:300px; /* width of popup */
    border:1px solid #eee; /* popup border */
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="click" rel="box1">popup 1</a>
<br><br>
<a class="click" rel="box2">popup 2</a>

<div id="box1" class="pop"> <div class="fade"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        yes
    </div>
</div>

<div id="box2" class="pop"> <div class="fade"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        no
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior? JavaScript makes `fadeToggle` first `.pop` and then second `.pop`. Second `.pop` will cover the first one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.